# CNN: Generate a confusion matrix for entire test dataset

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

I'm using following code to predict my model output on dataset.

```
correct = 0
total_predictions = []
actual_labels = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in testloader:
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
        
        outputs = model(images)
  
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        actual_labels.append(labels)
        total_predictions.append(final_pred)
        final_pred = torch.FloatTensor(final_pred).to(device)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
```

Now to generate a confusion matrix of entire dataset, I tried storing my predictions and test labels in a list and pass it to confusion_matrix in sklearn, but that fails with following error:

```
ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead.
```

Can someone help me in calculating confusion matrix for my entire dataset?

The following code only calculates it for the last batch:

```
 cf = confusion_matrix(predicted.cpu(), labels.cpu())
```

**Update-1**

Using @CutePoison's template, I'm getting this.

You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.

```
labels={}
labels['healthy_wheat'] = 0
labels['leaf_rust'] = 1
labels['stem_rust'] = 2

def conf_mat(y_true,y_pred,columns,**kwargs):
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred,labels = columns,**kwargs)
    df = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat,columns = columns, index = columns)
    df.columns.name="pred"
    df.index.name="true"
    return df

conf_mat(actual_labels,total_predictions ,columns =labels,normalize="true")
```

Comment: What fails? What is the error message?

Comment: @CutePoison If I use 'total_predictions' and 'actual_labels' which are both lists I get the following error: ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this snippet for createing confusion matrices, which works for multiple classes

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def conf_mat(y_true,y_pred,columns,**kwargs):
    """
    Creates a "pretty" confusion matrix
    """

    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred,labels = columns,**kwargs)
    df = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat,columns = columns, index = columns)
    df.columns.name="pred"
    df.index.name="true"
    return df



conf_mat(actual_labels,final_pred ,columns =np.unique(actual_labels),normalize="true")
```

Note, you might want change the `columns` depending on how your labels are  created.

Furthmore your `final_pred` has to contain your class-prediction and not the score i.e `final_pred = [0,1,2,0...]` and not `final_pred= [[0.8,0.1,0.1], [0.1,0.7,0.2],[0.05,0.05,0.9],[0.75,0.2,0.05],...]`

Comment: Please have a look at my update. I provided the parameters as you explained, still getting the same error though.

Comment: Have you ensured that your `final_pred` is as per my answer? According to the error it seems like they are in the wrong format